# Why doesn't the kmeans function in python cluster in a correct way?

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I have some 2D data and want to cluster them into 6 groups. When I run the python code for that, the result doesnt seem to be correct!

```
df1=df[['AudReg','AudIrreg']]
model=KMeans(n_clusters=5, init='k-means++',max_iter=1000)
model.fit(df1)
centroids=model.cluster_centers_
df1_cluster=df1.copy()
df1_cluster['Cluster']=model.fit_predict(df1)
color=['red','blue','yellow','orange','black','cyan']
df1_cluster['color']=df1_cluster['Cluster'].map(lambda p:color[p])
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
plt.scatter(df1['AudReg'],df1['AudIrreg'], c=df1_cluster['color'])
plt.scatter(centroids[:,0],centroids[:,1], c='green', s=100)
plt.show()
```

so if you look at the area outlined with a red line, you see the dark blue points belong to that cluster but slassified as the members of the other cluster!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtAbG.png)
and this is not the first time, I see results of k-means clustering seem incorrect!

I tried clustering with different number of clusters or tried 3D data, but there are always some data points that seem to belong to a wrong cluster!
Does anyone knows what the problem is and how I can fix it?

Comment: I suggest either sharing a bit of your data or running your algorithm on a sample dataset that can be imported. That way the community can better help you.

Comment: You fit the model twice, possibly changing the identified controids.